# How JAXB/Jersey unmarshall Boolean values?

Tags: glassfish, jersey, jaxb2, glassfish-4

I have an issue with some RESTful services that takes a transfer object in parameter (basically an XML object that will be unmarshalled to a POJO).

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "myPojo")
public class MyPojo {
    @XmlElement(name = "myField")
    private Boolean myBoolean;

    public void setMyBoolean(Boolean bool) {
        myBoolean = bool;
    }

    public Boolean getMyBoolean()  {
        return myBoolean;
    }
}
```

And the service is something like that:

```
public class MyRestService {

    @PUT
    @Path("somewhere")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response update(MyPojo pojo) {
        System.out.println("Boolean value: " + pojo.getMyBoolean();
    }
}
```

If I post this XML fragment:

```
<myPojo>
    <myField>false</myField>
</myPojo>
```

I got:

```
Boolean value: false
```

And if I post this XML fragment:

```
<myPojo>
    <myField>FALSE</myField>
</myPojo>
```

I got:

```
Boolean value: null
```

I run that code under Glassfish 4 with Jersey 1.9.1 and JAXB 2.2.7. In addition, under Glassfish 2, I got a different behavior where both uppercase and lowercase are unmarshalled as expected.

So, I am really curious to know what is happening and why the marshalling of boolean is different.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use the primitive type rather than the wrapper type. You'll get, I assume, the value like [Boolean.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) gives.

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem today where JAXB returns null when parsing "FaLsE" or "True" on a Boolean field. Unfortunately, upgrading to 2.2.7 or above (2.2.11 as of today) didn't help me. When I dig deeper into the source code, it seems that the parsing logic happens inside DatatypeConverterImpl.java. And there is no configuration that can alter its behavior on uppercase.

[Link to JAXB DatatypeConverterImpl.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.7/com/sun/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl.java#DatatypeConverterImpl._parseBoolean%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

The solution that I found (and works), is to define a new BooleanAdapter and asks JAXB to use that instead. In the adapter, you can define whatever conversion logic that fits your application.

Custom BooleanAdapter.java

```
public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(v))
            return null;
        return Boolean.valueOf(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        return v.toString();
    }
}
```

Your model object

```
@XmlElement(name = "myField")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
public Boolean getMyBoolean() {
    return myBoolean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several investigations, we figured out that the version 2.2 of JAXB we are using seems to contain a bug that serialize the boolean values not as expected. I mean that for example: FaLsE will be converted to null value.

Upgrading to the version 2.2.7 has fixed our issue.

Comment: Interesting. We're using 2.2 as well, and observed a case where an incoming XML request with a value "True" for a boolean field making it `null` after the JAXB binding occurs.